# Aggregate as new column in R

Tags: r, awk, aggregate

Input:

```
Time,id1,id2
22:30,1,0
22:32,2,1
22:33,1,0
22:34,2,1
```

Output Desired

```
Time,Time2,id1,id2
22:30,22:33,1,0
22:32,22:34,2,1
```

Output by my code

```
Time,id1,id2
22:30,22:33,1,0
22:32,22:34,2,1
```

What change should I make to my code `aggregate(Time~,df,FUN=toString)`
My id1 and id2 together is the key and times are in and out time for each key. I need to get time in and time out as separate column values. Currently they are in column Time.

I tried it using awk also.

Comment: Unable to use correct formatting because of limited connection over 2g mobile. Please don't down vote

Comment: `aggregate(Time~.,df,FUN=toString)`

Comment: @Sotos that is what I'm already using

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use any packages, this will work:

```
df <- aggregate(Time~.,df,FUN=toString)
df
#output
id1 id2         Time
 1   0  22:30, 22:33
 2   1  22:32, 22:34

df$Time2 <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Time), ","),"[", 2)
df$Time <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Time), ","),"[", 1)
df
#output
id1 id2  Time  Time2
1   0   22:30  22:33
2   1   22:32  22:34
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`

```
$ cat time.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
}

function in_time() {
    n++
    store[id1, id2] = n
    itime[n] = time; iid1[n] = id1; iid2[n] = id2
}

function out_time(   i) {
    i = store[id1, id2]
    otime[i] = time
}


NR > 1 {
    time = $1; id1 = $2; id2 = $3
    if   ((id1, id2) in store) out_time()
    else                        in_time()
}

END {
    print "Time,id1,id2"
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        print itime[i], otime[i], iid1[i], iid2[i]
}
```

Usage:

```
awk -f time.awk file.dat
```